# How do I use Tkinter and Telebot together?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-telegram-bot

I've been working on a Python project where I'm stuck at one point. Basically, I have a GUI that updates automatically once 5 seconds. I have done it using the method `.after(5000, main)` where main function looks like the following.

```
def main():
    global lastthreshold
    global run
    global lastaction
    global bakiye
    global lif
    global gsecenek
    paributl, binancedolar, paribudolar, dolar = getData()
    farklow, farkhigh = diff(paributl, binancedolar, paribudolar)
    data = guiDataMaker(paributl, binancedolar, paribudolar, farklow, farkhigh)
    gui = Gui(data, dolar, lastthreshold, alsatmiktar, bakiye)
    #print(*data, sep="\n")
    #print(*cooldown.items(), sep="\n")
    if run:
        lif = gui.gui()
        for i in paributl.keys():
            cooldown[i] = "NONE"
        run = False
    gui.secenek.set(gsecenek)
    runbot = runBot(lastthreshold, bakiye, data, cooldown, alsatmiktar)
    if runbot[0] != None:
        currency, guncelfark, fiyat, newbakiye, buydate, islem = runbot
        bakiye = newbakiye
        guncelislem = (currency, guncelfark, fiyat, newbakiye, buydate, islem)
        lastaction = (currency, guncelfark, fiyat, newbakiye, buydate, islem)
        gui.updateGuiData(lif, cooldown, guncelislem)
    else:
        gui.updateGuiData(lif, cooldown, lastaction)

    src.after(5000, main)
    src.mainloop()
    
main()
#src.mainloop()
#bot.polling()
```

My actual code is something around 450 lines, so I think pasting it here would be a waste of space. Though, I can do that if it helps you help me more easily. Anyway, the above code works perfectly with a single thread which is created by `src.mainloop()`.

In the project, what I'm trying to do is basically a trading bot. To help the user see what is going on, I created a gui using Tkinter library. I create the gui only once and I only update the data every 5 seconds.

What I want to achieve is to create a Telegram Bot which the user can interact with. For example use should be able to type `/BTC-USD` to get information about bitcoin-dolar. So far, I achieved to send the user every buy/sell operation of the bot in telegram. However, what I'm stuck right now is to get commands of the user since it requires me to use `bot.polling()` which is another thread. Wherever I put this line of code in my code, it causes GUI to "not responding".

So in simpler words, my question is how can I have a Telegram Bot interacting with a user by sending messages and getting commands, also a GUI that is updated automatically every 5 seconds?

Comment: The secret is to have the GUI in its own thread and use events. For anything that blocks, it should be in its own thread. To communicate between the GUI and these threads you should use synchronised queues.

Comment: thanks for response, I forgot to mention that I also want the user to be able to set some parameters using Telegram. I mean the user should be able to type /setthreshold x and the updated threshold value should appear in the GUI. I could not get how to separate threading as you propose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: Wait for item in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141509/tkinter-wait-for-item-in-queue)

Comment: Thanks for help but even if it answers my question, I doubt I could understand what to do.