# How to use a timer or equivalent within a python thread without blocking the GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, timer, blocking

I am a writing a GUI based application using the PyQT framework which connects to a device, sends commands, reads the corresponding data and displays this in real time to a table, graph widget and to a file.

Once the run button is clicked it starts a thread which sends the external device commands according to a procedure table and emits signals with the data to various methods to change the GUI.

When the run button is clicked it executes the following lines:

```
worker = Worker(self.runProcedure)
worker.signals.updateResults.connect(self.updateResultsTable)
worker.signals.writeResults.connect(self.writeResultsFile)
worker.signals.finished.connect(self.procedure_complete) 
     
self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

within the runProcedure commands are sent to the device from the procedure table and the data read from the device is put into a list 'hfData' using code similar to that listed below:

```
while float(currentForceReading) <= float(target) and stopAlarm == 0:
    ts = dt.now().timestamp()
    hfData = (connection.readline()).split()
    updateResults_callback.emit(ts, hfData) #method to update results table and graphs
    writeResults_callback.emit(ts, hfData)  #method to write results to a file
```

One of the options in the application is to hold for a period of time where it continues collecting data from the device without sending new commands.

I am looking for a way to continue taking measurements whilst in this hold time and continue updating the GUI.

I have tried to implement the following code, however this while loop blocks the GUI from updating:

```
stepHoldTime = float(procedureModel.data(procedureModel.index(row,4), Qt.DisplayRole))
if(stepHoldTime != 0):
    endTime = time.monotonic() + stepHoldTime
    while(time.monotonic() < endTime):
        ts = dt.now().timestamp()
        hfData = (connection.readline()).split()
        updateResults_callback.emit(ts,hfData)
```

Is there a correct way to implement this functionality?

Comment: first you should say what GUI framework you use. Every framework should have method to execute some function periodically (or with delay) - `tkinter` has `after()`, `PyQt` has `QTimer()` - and you should use it instead of `while`-loop - and then it doesn't block GUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: Wait for item in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141509/tkinter-wait-for-item-in-queue)

Comment: @furas, I did forget to state the GUI framework and I have updated the question to reflect I am using PyQT. I did look at the QTimer Class and tried to implement using the line 'while(remaingTime > 0)' as I want the actions to occur until the timer ends. This didn't seem to block the GUI entirely unless the user clicks in the application but the timer did not decrease. Could you provide a short example how to implement this functionality using the QTimer class?

Comment: instead of `'while(remaingTime > 0)' ` you should use `QTimer(time, function)` and this function should run code without loop but with another `QTimer(time, function)` at the end. Eventually `QTimer` should run function periodically (many times) and function should run code without `while`-loop because `QTimer` will repeate it .

Comment: I can show how to use QTimer on some simple example - ie. displaying current time. But if you have more complex code (ie. using threads) then this example can be useless and you may need something more complex - but first you would have to show minimal working code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `while`-loop you could run `QTimer` which will execute code every few milliseconds.

It is minimal example which shows how to run function every 1000ms and update time in label.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QDateTime

class Window(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.showTime()
        
        help(QTimer)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def showTime(self):
        text = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
        self.setText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

---

But your problem can be more complex and it may need more complex solution. You may have to show minimal working code which we could run and see problem - and test some ideas to resolve problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your "reader" from a separate thread

```
class YourUi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    update_data = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(YourUi, self).__init__()
        self.update_data.connect(self.do_update_data)

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.update_worker, args=(self.update_data,), daemon=True)
        t.start()

    @staticmethod
    def update_worker(signal):
        connection = create_conncetion()
        while True:
            hfData = (connection.readline()).split()
            signal.emit(hfData)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def do_update_data(self, hf_data):
        # access GUI elemetns from main thread to prevent freezing
        self.some_qt_label.setText(str(hf_data))
```